# C++ build inject/replace included library

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, code-injection, tensorflow-lite

([`tflm`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro)) includes a class from another library ([`ruy`](https://github.com/google/ruy)) whose functionality always results in a [no-op](https://github.com/google/ruy/blob/38a9266b832767a3f535a74a9e0cf39f7892e594/ruy/profiler/instrumentation.h#L188). Sadly the `ruy` library dependency is required when building `tflm`.

Looking for assistance for how to inject/replace the `ruy` include so that the `ruy` library is not needed.

Within a cmake build rule I could replicate the directory/filepath and push text for the class signature, but is there a better/cleaner way?

Typical usage of `ruy` in `tflm`:

```
#include "ruy/profiler/instrumentation.h"

inline void Func() {
  ruy::profiler::ScopeLabel label("Bar");
}
```

where `ruy::profiler::ScopeLabel` results in a no-op.

Note, the underlying cause of this is `tflm` using the `tfl` codebase where `ruy` can be enabled.

Comment: ... if it's a no-op, why wouldn't you compiler optimize it out? Do you have any evidence that it isn't optimized out? And if it is optimized out, what's the problem? Is ruy a shared library that's being linked to? And is ruy used for any other purpose by tflm?

Comment: It will be optimized out, no problems there. I am trying to avoid requiring the ruy library in my repo.

Comment: "_Is ruy a shared library that's being linked to? And is ruy used for any other purpose by tflm?_"